# How to calculate ratio between 2 columns in R (with a function)?

Tags: r, rstudio

we are running an experiment that checks the effect of brand on product value.
In order to calculate the results, we first need to calculate the ratio between 2 answers to the same product.
We want to do it by a function and not manual.
for example

```
prod1_nobrand prod1_brand prod2_nobrand prod2_brand
1             2           4             8
2             6           5             20
```

[image]

we want to create a new column for each ratio
for example

```
prod1_ratio prod2_ratio
2           2
3           4
```

any idea how to do that?
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The simple base R way to do that would be as follows...

```
yourdataframe$new_ratio_col <- yourdataframe$prod1 / yourdataframe$prod2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I'm understanding your ask correctly. But my feeling is that you should familiarize yourself with `dplyr` functions. You can use the `mutate` function to create new columns in this way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
mutate(prod1_ratio = prod1_nobrand  / prod2 prod1_brand)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is the put it into long form, calculate the ratio, then pivot back to wide form with `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c("num", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(ratio = brand / nobrand) %>% 
  select(-ends_with("brand")) %>% 
  group_by(num) %>% 
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "num", values_from = "ratio", names_glue = "{num}_ratio") %>% 
  select(-rowid)
```

**Output**

```
  prod1_ratio prod2_ratio
        <dbl>       <dbl>
1           2           2
2           3           4
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(prod1_nobrand = 1:2, prod1_brand = c(2L, 6L), 
    prod2_nobrand = 4:5, prod2_brand = c(8L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the columns are paired like in the given example `c(FALSE, TRUE)` and `c(TRUE, FALSE)` could be used to subset and make the division.

```
y <- x[c(FALSE, TRUE)] / x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
names(y) <- sub("_.*", "_ratio", names(y))
y
#  prod1_ratio prod2_ratio
#1           2           2
#2           3           4
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(prod1_nobrand = 1:2, prod1_brand = c(2L, 6L),
                prod2_nobrand = 4:5, prod2_brand = c(8L, 20L))
```